# Getting the description of the parent statement in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Simple enough question, is there a way to get the description of the parent (`it`) statement in Mocha on Node.js?

So for example:

```
describe("Describe test", function(){
    it("Describe this specific test", function(){
        console.log(message); // Where message is "Describe this specific test"
    });
});
```

I mainly need this for writing log files automatically and accurately. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following

```
describe("Describe test", function(){
  it("Describe this specific test", function(){
    console.log('Title:', this._runnable.title);
  });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: Scratch the above comment, I had my code enclosed in a setTimeout block, duh.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/620